# Adding thumbnails of images to save in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, image

Here's the code to add an thumb image. It is reading the image fine and even when I save the thumbnail in a folder, it does fine. I just can't get it saved in the database. The $x is a counter in a loop.

If I read the image and save it in the database without changing the size, it works but not after I change the size.

```
// Create the thumbnail

$picture = "images/" . str_replace(" ", '%20', $images[$x]);
$image = file_get_contents("$picture");
$source = imagecreatefromstring($image);

$width = imagesx($source);
$height = imagesy($source);

$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth, $newHeight);
imagecopyresampled($thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newWidth, $newHeight, $width, $height);

echo "image created";

// End thumbnail creation


$thumb = mysql_real_escape_string($thumb);
$query = "UPDATE tablename SET thumb = '$thumb' WHERE id = $x";

$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: You can't save __resource__ in database. What is the type of `thumb` field in db?

Comment: should that not be an `INSERT` statement?

Comment: No, I already have the file name in the database. I just need to add the thumb to it.

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: There is no client side on this.

Comment: :), but this is still not the right way to make SQL statements. Use prepared statements all the time, even if the code is just for yourself.

Comment: **WARNING**: Do not use the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface which was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Here parameters are **NOT** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and this has severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) in this code. Escape **any** and all user data, especially from `$_POST` or `$_GET`.

Comment: Why do people keep voting this down? If someone doesn't know something, they should ask. How is that a bad question. I'm just learning this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your database column to Binary Large OBject (BLOB). As you can't upload images to database you must convert image to binary format and then upload it. Supposing you're getting it from a form that's your PHP code.

```
<?php
if(isset($_FILES['image']['name'])){
// *** Add your validation code here *** //
// Include Connection
     include_once('conn.php');

 // Get Image
 $name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
 $type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
 $get_content = file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
 $escape = mysql_real_escape_string($get_content);
 $sql = "INSERT INTO `img`.`dbimg` (`ID`, `name`, `src`, `type`) VALUES (NULL, '$name', '$escape', '$type');";
 if(mysql_query($sql)){
 echo 'Image inserted to database';
 }else{
 echo 'Error data inserting';
 }
}
?>
```

Comment: For the most part, that's what I have. What's with the extra(i.e. id, name, src, type)?

Comment: ID, you can set it to null if you have auto increment option in your database, name is the name of the file itself, type, is the type of image: PNG, JPEG etc... src is the binary content which you need to escape. In fact you can see that in the code you're passing the value $escape which is the escape_string of $get_content variable.

Comment: But I would like to know why you want it in binary on your database... Why don't you simply store the image in the server storage and just put the path inside the database. This solution is much more faster and secure.

Comment: That's what I finally did. After figuring it out I found out that I am not allowed enough room in my database to add them all.  Thanks!